# Add SRT subtitle to video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

I use ffmpeg to encode, and add subtitle to a video by following command

```
$ ffmpeg -i hifi.avi -i hifi.srt -acodec libfaac -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -vpre ipod640 -s 480x240 -b 256k -scodec copy  hifi.m4v -newsubtitle
```

Here is the output

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.git, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug  4 2011 11:11:39 with gcc 4.5.2
  configuration: --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-memalign-hack --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac --arch=x86 --enable-swscale --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-debug=3
  libavutil    51. 11. 1 / 51. 11. 1
  libavcodec   53.  9. 1 / 53.  9. 1
  libavformat  53.  6. 0 / 53.  6. 0
  libavdevice  53.  2. 0 / 53.  2. 0
  libavfilter   2. 27. 5 /  2. 27. 5
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, avi, from 'hifi.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.4.1 (build 2178/release)
    IAS1            : English
  Duration: 01:49:02.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 897 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile), yuv420p, 544x304 [SAR 1:1 DAR 34:19], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 32 kb/s
[srt @ 0152c100] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, srt, from 'hifi.srt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 56.080000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1.0: Subtitle: srt
File 'hifi.m4v' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[buffer @ 02548920] w:544 h:304 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:1/1 sws_param:
[scale @ 02558ee0] w:544 h:304 fmt:yuv420p -> w:480 h:240 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
[libx264 @ 02547f20] Default settings detected, using medium profile
[libx264 @ 02547f20] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 02547f20] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 02547f20] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 02547f20] 264 - core 115 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=256 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=10000 vbv_bufsize=10000 nal_hrd=none ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, ipod, to 'hifi.m4v':
    Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuv420p, 480x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:1], q=2-31, 256 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libfaac, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0.2: Subtitle: srt
    Stream #0.3: Subtitle: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
  Stream #1.0 -> #0.2
  Stream #1.0 -> #0.3
Encoder (codec id 0) not found for output stream #0.3
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong with my command?

Answer (score 14):

The MP4 container does not support SubRip subtitles, only a special `mov_text` format.

### Option 1: Convert subtitles to `mov_text`

```
ffmpeg -i hifi.avi -i hifi.srt -acodec libfaac -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -vpre ipod640 -s 480x240 -b 256k -scodec mov_text hifi.m4v
```

### Option 2: Use an MKV container

iPod will not support this, however on iPod touch you can install third party software to play MKV files.

```
ffmpeg -i hifi.avi -i hifi.srt -acodec libfaac -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -vpre ipod640 -s 480x240 -b 256k -scodec copy hifi.mkv
```

### Option 3: Burn in the subtitles to the video

May require additional steps to work, especially if you're on Windows. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo for more information.

```
ffmpeg -i hifi.avi -vf subtitles=hifi.srt -acodec libfaac -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -vpre ipod640 -s 480x240 -b 256k hifi.m4v
```

Comment: Nice i was looking what the end subtitle format is, as you stated, its mov_text, is there any other container which supports subrip?

Comment: With both options 1 & 2, I get **"File for preset 'ipod640' not found"**
(ffmpeg 6.0)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the command to Add srt file to video using FFmpeg in Windows Environment

```
ffmpeg -i Video.wmv -i hi.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -crf 23 video-with-subtitles.mkv
```

Comment: `-crf 23` is ignored when using `-c copy`, so you can omit `-crf 23`. You should properly format your command so it looks nicer like the other answers.

Comment: For a moment it seemed that I solved this subtitles pain ... But it was only because the MKV file that I created had the same main name with my SRT so VLC used it to display subtitles. So, the pain remains. I cannot find a way to show SRT (or other type) subtitles embedded into an MP4 or SubRip subtitles embedded into a MKV file ...

Answer (score 2):

It appears that two subtitle tracks are trying to be added, one of which has no codec.  More recent versions of ffmpeg do not use `-newsubtitle`, so that might be your problem.

**Try leaving off `-newsubtitle`.**

Comment: thanks, but it doesnt works, I found out that ffmpeg doesnt support text streams in mp4 and m4v container. It does work with mkv. I changed to mplayer/mencoder.

Answer (score 2):

very first install 'libass' library in your linux. after that configure ffmpeg with the command

```
./configure --enable-libass --disable-yasm --enable-libfreetype
```

after that copy your srt in the ffmpeg directory then use these command

```
ffmpeg -i subtitle.srt subtitle.ass
ffmpeg -i input.flv -vf ass=subtitle.ass output.flv
```

Comment: The OP's subtitles are in SubRip format, not Advanced SubStation. However, if burning in the subtitles is desired, `subtitles=hifi.srt` can be used instead, as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Batch file.

Just drop 2 files on it at the same time - .mp4 and .srt to get a .mkv video with embedded subtitles.

If you want the original/low video quality, just comment/uncomment the appropriate line in the code.

Among all other things, I made an asynchronous call of msgBox. Who needs it - copy it to your sources.

For some reason, it doesn't accept parentheses () in file names. I did not check the rest of the characters.

```
    @echo off
    if "%~x1"==".mp4" (
        set mp4=%~n1
        set path=%~d1%~p1
    )
    if "%~x2"==".mp4" (
        set mp4=%~n2
        set path=%~d1%~p1
    )
    if "%~x1"==".srt" set srt=%~1
    if "%~x2"==".srt" set srt=%~2
    if not "%mp4%"=="" (
        if not "%srt%"=="" (
            :: If your original ffmpeg.exe file located in system32 directory then replace "%~dp0ffmpeg.exe" to ffmpeg
            :: original quality
            ::"%~dp0ffmpeg.exe" -i "%path%%mp4%.mp4" -i "%srt%" -ar 48000 -vcodec libx264 -disposition:s:0 default -scodec copy "%path%%mp4%.mkv"
            :: low quality
            "%~dp0ffmpeg.exe" -i "%path%%mp4%.mp4" -i "%srt%" -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -s 480x240 -b 256k -disposition:s:0 default -scodec copy "%path%%mp4%.mkv"
            call :msgbox "File %path%%mp4%.mkv completed."
        ) else call :msgbox "File .srt missing in the input parameters`r`nJust drop 2 files with extensions:`r`n.mp4 - video and .srt - subtitles`r`nto this batch file to get .mkv with subtitles"
    ) else call :msgbox "File .mp4 missing in the input parameters`r`nJust drop 2 files with extensions:`r`n.mp4 - video and .srt - subtitles`r`nto this batch file to get .mkv with subtitles"
    goto :eof
    :msgBox [msgText]
    C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").Run ""powershell -Command """"[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')|Out-Null;"""" """"[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(\""""%~1\"""")"""""",0,false:close")
    exit /B
```

Answer (score -1):

Better

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -f srt -i infile.srt -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text outfile.mp4
```

Comment: Why is this "better"?

Comment: FYI, a _whole bunch_ of your old answers are popping up in the Low Quality Posts review queue right now, including this one and [an exact duplicate answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17584262/354577). Mostly ones that have no context or explanation, just "copy this and trust me".